# gcc Error while configuring apache 2.2.21

Tags: linux, apache, gcc, configuration, glibc

I'm trying to install Apache 2.2.21 on my Suse linux but when i run the ./configure with the different options i get following Error:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/opt/Apache22 --enable-ssl --enable-logio --with-ssl=/opt/ssl

checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library ...

checking for APR... reconfig
configuring package in srclib/apr now
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configuring APR library
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
APR Version: 1.4.5
checking for chosen layout... apr
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: in `/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
configure failed for srclib/apr
```

Here is the correct log file.

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ /opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr/configure --disable-option-checking --prefix=/opt/Apache22 --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr --prefix=/opt/Apache22 --exec-prefix=/opt/Apache22 --libdir=${prefix}/lib --includedir=/opt/Apache22/include --bindir=${prefix}/bin --datadir=/opt/Apache22 --with-installbuilddir=${prefix}/build

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = sap9
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.16.60-0.54.5-default
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 Fri Sep 4 01:28:03 UTC 2009

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/TradeXpress5/users/editest/bin
PATH: /opt/TradeXpress5/bin
PATH: /opt/TradeXpress5/bin/runner/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin/X11


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3787: checking build system type
configure:3801: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3821: checking host system type
configure:3834: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3854: checking target system type
configure:3867: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3930: checking for working mkdir -p
configure:3946: result: yes
configure:4038: checking for chosen layout
configure:4040: result: apr
configure:4305: checking for gcc
configure:4321: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4332: result: gcc
configure:4561: checking for C compiler version
configure:4570: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4581: $? = 0
configure:4570: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-threads=posix --prefix=/usr --with-local-prefix=/usr/local --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.1.2 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-libgcj --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --program-suffix= --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --without-system-libunwind --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)
configure:4581: $? = 0
configure:4570: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:4581: $? = 1
configure:4570: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: no input files
configure:4581: $? = 1
configure:4603: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4625: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/lib64/libc.so.6: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4629: $? = 1
configure:4666: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| FILE *f = fopen ("conftest.out", "w");
|  return ferror (f) || fclose (f) != 0;
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4672: error: in `/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr':
configure:4676: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_mkdir_p=yes
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
APR_CONFIG_LOCATION='source'
APR_DOTTED_VERSION='1.4.5'
APR_LIBNAME=''
APR_MAJOR_VERSION='1'
AR=''
AS=''
ASCPP=''
AWK=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFAULT_OSDIR=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
ECHO='echo'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_CFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS=''
EXTRA_INCLUDES=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LIBS=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
GREP=''
INCLUDES=''
INCLUDE_OUTPUTS=''
INCLUDE_RULES=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_SUBDIRS=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTFLAGS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_LDFLAGS=''
LT_NO_INSTALL=''
LT_VERSION=''
MKDEP=''
NMEDIT=''
NOTEST_CFLAGS=''
NOTEST_CPPFLAGS=''
NOTEST_INCLUDES=''
NOTEST_LDFLAGS=''
NOTEST_LIBS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJECTS_PLATFORM=''
OBJEXT=''
OSDIR=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RM=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_F77=''
acceptfilter=''
apr_builddir='/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr'
apr_builders='/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr/build'
apr_charset_ebcdic=''
apr_has_user=''
apr_has_xthread_files=''
apr_inaddr_none=''
apr_procattr_user_set_requires_password=''
apr_srcdir='/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr'
apr_tcp_nopush_flag=''
apr_thread_func=''
aprdso=''
aprlfs=''
arpa_ineth=''
bigendian=''
bindir='${prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
conioh=''
crypth=''
ctypeh=''
datadir='/opt/Apache22'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
direnth=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
eolstr=''
errnoh=''
exec_prefix='/opt/Apache22'
export_lib_target=''
fcntlh=''
fcntlser=''
file_as_socket=''
flockser=''
fork=''
hasfcntlser=''
hasflockser=''
hasposixser=''
hasprocpthreadser=''
hassysvser=''
have_corkable_tcp=''
have_getrlimit=''
have_in_addr=''
have_inet_addr=''
have_inet_network=''
have_iovec=''
have_ipv6=''
have_memchr=''
have_memmove=''
have_proc_invoked=''
have_sa_storage=''
have_sctp=''
have_setrlimit=''
have_sigaction=''
have_sigsuspend=''
have_sigwait=''
have_strcasecmp=''
have_strdup=''
have_stricmp=''
have_strncasecmp=''
have_strnicmp=''
have_strstr=''
have_unicode_fs=''
have_union_semun=''
havebeosarea=''
havemmapanon=''
havemmapshm=''
havemmaptmp=''
havemmapzero=''
haveos2shm=''
haveshmget=''
haveshmgetanon=''
havewin32shm=''
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='/opt/Apache22/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
ino_t_value=''
installbuilddir='${datadir}/build-${APR_MAJOR_VERSION}'
int64_literal=''
int64_t_fmt=''
int64_value=''
int_value=''
ioh=''
lib_target=''
libdir='${prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/modules'
limitsh=''
link=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}'
long_value=''
lt_compile=''
mandir='${prefix}/man'
mmap=''
netdbh=''
netinet_inh=''
netinet_sctp_uioh=''
netinet_sctph=''
netinet_tcph=''
o_nonblock_inherited=''
oc=''
off_t_fmt=''
off_t_value=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
osuuid=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pid_t_fmt=''
posixser=''
prefix='/opt/Apache22'
proc_mutex_is_global=''
processh=''
proclockglobal=''
procpthreadser=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
pthreadh=''
pthreadser=''
rand=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
semaphoreh=''
sendfile=''
sharedmem=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
shlibpath_var=''
short_value=''
signalh=''
size_t_fmt=''
size_t_value=''
so_ext=''
socklen_t_value=''
ssize_t_fmt=''
ssize_t_value=''
stdargh=''
stdint=''
stdioh=''
stdlibh=''
stringh=''
stringsh=''
struct_rlimit=''
sys_ioctlh=''
sys_sendfileh=''
sys_signalh=''
sys_socketh=''
sys_sockioh=''
sys_syslimitsh=''
sys_timeh=''
sys_typesh=''
sys_uioh=''
sys_unh=''
sys_waith=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/conf'
sysvser=''
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='unknown'
tcp_nodelay_inherited=''
threads=''
timeh=''
top_builddir='/opt/httpd-2.2.21/srclib/apr'
uint64_literal=''
uint64_t_fmt=''
uint64_t_hex_fmt=''
unistdh=''
usebeosarea=''
usemmapanon=''
usemmapshm=''
usemmaptmp=''
usemmapzero=''
useos2shm=''
useshmget=''
useshmgetanon=''
usewin32shm=''
voidp_size=''
windowsh=''
winsock2h=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

It probably has to do with:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

gcc is located under /usr/bin/gcc but i don't think the problem is the ./config not finding it. Could it maybe be that the reason lies with a newer version glibc beeing installed on the system? If so [this would be my root problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672463/how-can-i-delete-remove-a-glibc-version-so-the-older-version-is-used-again) if you will.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we are looking at the wrong config.log here. "configure failed for srclib/apr", so could you please post srclib/apr/config.log?

Comment: omg ur right that... i feel stupid. After a day of work it's hard to stay alert

Comment: Why are you building such a standard piece of software like Apache from source? Does SuSE not provide packages for it? What sort of insanity is this?
Edit: Wow, I just noticed the obscenely old kernel and compiler versions listed there. Are you really planning on running a server on that? A kernel that hasn't been patched in two years is apt to have a lot of security holes in it. If an attacker gets any foothold at all, you're screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded binutils, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that it might be due to `target_vendor='unknown' with a value unknown. That would be my first port of call.

Answer (score 0):

Install the gcc again with dependencies and the dependent modules as shown below and try ./configure again to fix the above issue

```
# rpm -ivh gcc-4.1.2-14.el5.i386.rpm glibc-devel-2.5-18.i386.rpm glibc-headers-2.5-18.i38
6.rpm kernel-headers-2.6.18-53.el5.i386.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
1:kernel-headers         ########################################### [ 25%]
2:glibc-headers          ########################################### [ 50%]
3:glibc-devel            ########################################### [ 75%]
4:gcc                    ########################################### [100%]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have compile and build pcre,apr and apr-util before configuring apache.